# How do you make an Ethernet network interface silent on layer 2 and above?

Tags: networking, iptables

I would like to be able to make a single Ethernet interface on Ubuntu 18.04 silent and receive only. No traffic out at layer 2 or above, no responses to traffic inbound.

I have initially tried the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

SNIFFIF=$1

echo $SNIFFIF

ip link set $SNIFFIF down
ip addr flush dev $SNIFFIF
ip -6 addr flush dev $SNIFFIF
ip link set dev $SNIFFIF arp off
ip route flush dev $SNIFFIF
iptables -I OUTPUT -o $SNIFFIF -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -o $SNIFFIF -j DROP
ip6tables -I OUTPUT -o $SNIFFIF -j DROP
ip6tables -I FORWARD -o $SNIFFIF -j DROP
ip link set $SNIFFIF up
```

There are still issues with this. Both dhclient and avahi-daemon send traffic. I have uninstalled avahi-daemon to solve part of this, but I want to keep dhclient and I want to be able to mistakenly run dhclient against this interface without anything being sent out.

This is reportedly because dhclient uses raw sockets, bypassing iptables.

Ideally there would be a failsafe way of blocking all outbound traffic.

Is there a way, on a single box, to achieve this goal?